# how to create a migration file for columns that already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a migration and ran it in a git branch but then did not merge the branch. However, the db columns from that migration continue to exist and I in fact still need them. Since there's no migration file for them (because I didn't merge the branch), I created a new migration but obviously can't run it, because the columns already exist. I therefore renamed the file by giving it a number that made it seem as if it was an earlier migration -- I thought Rails would think that the migration had been run if I changed the number on the file. However, that hasn't worked. Now anytime I run a migration, it's getting aborted because I have this migration file in it that hasn't run but for which the columns already exist. I can delete this file but that won't help me when I push to production.

What do you do in this situation?

I'm using postgres if it matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then generate the migration in your other branch and

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails checks if a migration has already been run by comparing the migration numbers of the files from `db/migrate/` directory with the numbers it finds in the `schema_migrations` table. If you want to pretend that the migration has already been run, just manually insert the migration number into this table.
However, this is just an ugly workaround, it definitely should not be something to use often - and **never** use it in production.